# Correct position of edge labels in a graph plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

a = np.reshape(np.random.random_integers(0,1,size=25),(5,5)) # random 5,5 numpy-array
np.fill_diagonal(a,0)   # remove self-loops                                     
print "np-array: \n" + str(a)

D = nx.DiGraph(a)      # create directional graph from numpy array
weighted_edges = dict(zip(D.edges(),np.random.randint(1,10,size=len(D.edges())))) # assign random weights to each edge
edge_tuple_list =  [(key[0],key[1],value) for key,value in zip(weighted_edges.keys(),weighted_edges.values())] 
D.add_weighted_edges_from(edge_tuple_list) #convert to list of edge tuples and add to the graph

nx.draw(D,with_labels=True,pos=nx.spring_layout(D),node_size=700) #draw the graph
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(D,pos=nx.spring_layout(D),edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(D,'weight')) #add edge labels
```

Which produces the image below. How to correct the positions of edge labels?

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call `pos=nx.spring_layout(G)` it recalculates `pos`, which starts with random positions and then iteratively updates them.  The final outcome is not unique -- depending on the initial values, the outcome can be very different.  So the first time you plotted the network it calculated some positions, but when you put the edge labels it calculated new positions.

So you want to create a `pos` dict which will save the same positions throughout.  I've only made changes to the last 3 lines of the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

a = np.reshape(np.random.random_integers(0,1,size=25),(5,5)) # random 5,5 numpy-array
np.fill_diagonal(a,0)   # remove self-loops                                     
print "np-array: \n" + str(a)

D = nx.DiGraph(a)      # create directional graph from numpy array
weighted_edges = dict(zip(D.edges(),np.random.randint(1,10,size=len(D.edges())))) # assign random weights to each edge
edge_tuple_list =  [(key[0],key[1],value) for key,value in zip(weighted_edges.keys(),weighted_edges.values())] 
D.add_weighted_edges_from(edge_tuple_list) #convert to list of edge tuples and add to the graph

pos = nx.spring_layout(D) # <---this line is new.  the pos here replaces nx.spring_layout below.
nx.draw(D, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size=700) #draw the graph
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(D, pos=pos, edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(D,'weight')) #add edge labels
```

[image]